# Confused in the usage of "where" in a non-interrogative sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, question-mark

I was writing an essay, but I came across a weird sentence:

> *Where peace prevails, justice prevails.*

In the above sentence, I am confused if the usage of "**where**" at the beginning of the sentence is grammatically correct or not. Should I avoid making sentences like these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence is irreproachable.  It would mean exactly the same if the relative *where* clause were at the end:

- Justice prevails where peace prevails.

except for a difference in emphasis.  It's like the difference between

- If we have peace, then we will have justice.
- We will have justice if we have peace.

That *where* (like most relative pronouns in English and related languages) can also be a question-word should not concern you; no one will think you're asking

- Where will peace prevail?

Comment: Yes, but some modern grammars (like H&Ps _CGEL_) classify "where" as a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ So it would be a relative preposition here, right?

Comment: Yes, a preposition in a 'fused' relative construction.

Comment: @BillJ +1 (thought it might be useful for readers!)